# Alternatives to handle customizer settings

Tags: theme-development, customization

My theme JBST (https://github.com/bassjobsen/jamedo-bootstrap-start-theme) makes use of https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API.

I need possibility to add some default settings to the customizer. I know `add_setting()` has the option to add an default value. Using this default value seems to give troubles for child themes to define it's own default settings.

I found some kind of solution already:

initialization of the customizer:

```
 $wp_customize->add_setting( 'color', array(
'default'        => false
) );
```

see also: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/26817

In my theme files:

```
$color = get_theme_mod( 'color',color);
if(!empty($color))
    //check for empty cause there will be a fallbback
    //fallback doesn't need the declaration below
{
    echo 'color:               '.$color.';';
}
```

in functions.php of the parent theme:

```
function jbst_default_settings()
{
do_action('jbst_child_settings');
if(!defined('color'))define('color','#ED9C28');//default
}
```

in functions.php of the child theme:

```
add_action('jbst_child_settings','sample_jbst_child_settings');
function sample_jbst_child_settings()
{
    define('color','red');//child theme's default
}
```

I wonder of someone could provide me a better / alternative solution?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you could add your own `jbst_default_color` filter to the default color value:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'color', array(
    'default'        => apply_filters( 'jbst_default_color', $color = '#ED9C28' )
) );
```

where you would add this to the child theme:

```
/**
 * Change the default color
 */
function childtheme_jbst_default_color( $color )
{
       $color = 'red';
       return $color;
}

add_filter( 'jbst_default_color', 'childtheme_jbst_default_color', 99, 1 );
```

to modify the default color settings.

Or even play with the `theme_mod_{$name}` filter that is applied everytime your call:

```
 get_theme_mod( $name, $default = false )
```

where you would be interested in `theme_mod_color`.

Comment: Thanks for your aswer. I like your filter idea, i will check this soon. One problem i found is wp_customize->add_setting was only call after the customizer runs and not after activation. (Maybe i have to call the customizer setting on init too)